# Plasma recovery at wakefield accelerators

Tags: plasma-physics, accelerator-physics

It seems that the current design requires filling the accelerator channel with dielectric plasma before use. Is there any way to quickly recover and quickly fill the dielectric plasma in the acceleration channel?

Comment: What do you mean by "quickly"?  Usually the chamber is as close to vacuum as you can make it and you keep the vacuum pumps running during the tests.  You fire a laser at a target to generate a plasma (i.e., ablate and ionize the material) then measure things in a matter of microseconds.